# Nodejs: Unirest: How to upload file with multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, file-upload, multipartform-data, unirest

I have a nodejs application, which is trying to upload a file to a springboot application by calling an API using unirest.

Below is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var unirest = require("unirest");
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.use(fileUpload());

app.all('/api/upload', function(req, res, next) {

                    restClient(req,res).then(function(result){
                        let data = result.body;
                        res.send(data);

                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        let data = err.error;
                        res.status(err.statusCode).send(data);
                   });
  });

function restClient(req, res) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var reqClient = unirest(req.method, req.url);
            let file = req.files.file;
            let filepath = file.name;
            file.mv(filepath, function(err) {
                if (err) reject(err);
            reqClient.headers({
                    "cache-control": "no-cache",
                    "Connection": "keep-alive",
                    "Content-Length": req.headers['Content-Length'],
                    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
                    "Host": "localhost:8080",
                    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                    "Accept": "*/*",
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + req.session.access_token,
                    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    "content-type": req.headers['content-type']
                    });

                    reqClient.multipart([
                    {
                        "body": fs.createReadStream(filepath)
                    },
                    {
                        "body": "fileType"
                    }
                    ]);
                });

            reqClient.end(function(resClient) {
                if (resClient.error) {
                    reject(resClient);
                } else {
                    resolve(resClient);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

I'm Getting the following error from the Spring-boot application.

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Header section has more than 10240 bytes (maybe it is not properly terminated)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.readHeaders(MultipartStream.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:854) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3073) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1095) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at com.ge.bfe.controller.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

And I have set multipart size also in application.properties file like below:

```
multipart.max-file-size=50MB
multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

when I'm hitting from postman it's working.
And the upload file size is 11KB.

Therefore, what could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change application.properties as below

`spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB`

For  spring boot 1.x try this
`spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
spring.http.multipart.enabled=true`
Also, Check this out :
https://config9.com/apps/tomcat/how-to-set-the-max-size-of-upload-file/

I guess the way you are uploading file may not be correct. you can try below code:

```
unirest
  .post('http://mockbin.com/request')
  .headers({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
  .field('parameter', 'value') // Form field
  .attach('file', 'path to file or pass stream here') // Attachment
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.body)
  })
```

Comment: my springboot version is: 1.3.0.RELEASE

Comment: Are you sure the way you uploading file is correct ?

Comment: From Postman, if I hit the API, it's working. And from postman i generate the code for Unirest and using that to make this call

Comment: facing the same issue. any solution